# How can you specify the description of the attachment with `pdftk`?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript, pdftk

In the documentation of PDFTK is not mentioned how to do it. The command:

```
pdftk file.pdf attach_files attachDoc.pdf to_page 2 output -
```

will attach a file to page 2 of the original `file.pdf` and output the result to `<stdout>`.

`attachDoc.pdf` is the file name of the filesystem. But I can not specify any description for this to show the attachment in the final file with an appropriate notation-description.

This would be especially useful, as in the automatic generation operations, the attachments often have temporary names assigned by the server and a description would be necessary

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

> You cannot (currently) add the description of a file attachment when using `pdftk`.
>     <sub>(However, it should be not too complicated to add this feature, because it only requires an additional key entry `/Desc` to the file attachment dictionary... Maybe you should submit a feature request to the `pdftk` developers?)</sub>

***Longer answer:***

You may be able to achieve what you want with the help of (a very recent version of) Ghostscript. ***But be warned, it is quite complicated!***

It requires the usage of the special PostScript extension that defines the **[`pdfmark` operator](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdfmarkReference_v9.pdf)**. This operator was created to insert advanced features into a PDF file which cannot be used within PostScript itself.

I'll demonstrate it with the help of a separate file which uses a series of `pdfmark` operations to insert a text file into a PDF. This is the content of text file, `mypdfmark-for-attachments.ps`:

```
 [                                           /NamespacePush  pdfmark
 [ /_objdef {fstream} /type /stream          /OBJ            pdfmark
 [ {fstream} << /Type /EmbeddedFile >>       /PUT            pdfmark

 [ {fstream} (I only simulate text file content here...)
                                             /PUT            pdfmark
 [ /Name <feff 0044 005a 005a 005a 005a 005a>
   /FS<<
      /Desc  (dEsCrIpTiOn)
      /Type  /Filespec
      /F     (my.txt)
      /EF    <<
             /F {fstream}
             >>
      >>                                     /EMBED          pdfmark
 [ {fstream}                                 /CLOSE          pdfmark
 [                                           /NamespacePop   pdfmark
```

As you can see, the `/Desc` key holds my description text `dEsCrIpTiOn`.

Now run this Ghostscript command:

```
gs -o emb.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite mypdfmark-for-attachments.ps -f some.pdf
```

Here is a screenshot of the resulting PDF file as shown by Acrobat:

[image: Acrobat screenshot]